# I'm trying to recreate my logo in Blender but I'm out of ideas

Tags: shaders, lighting, shadows, effects, emission

I have made this a long time ago in Photoshop 3D when it had more support for some effects and was easier to customize.
[image: Primary design]

I've been playing around with Blender for the first time now and i'm trying to make something alike but it's difficult, I managed to create the object from a .svg, extrude it and add a background, texture them some and after hours figure out why light wasn't really doing anything. This is where I'm at but I just can't figure this out. (background changed from white to hex:151515)

[image: Blender made logo]

Basically i'll change some settings and get a different result, some wanted things and some things that I don't understand, I'm basically lost in all the settings and don't really know what the things i'm changing are really doing.

I'm using emission for the red on the sides but I don't know how to control it.
The edges seem pixelated and I don't know what to do about that.
The white face of the object feels super bright.
The red emission between parts of the logo is so bright it feels like it's just one solid color instead of being a shape and has no shaddow.

I know it's a tall order but I don't know what to do anymore, i've watched hours of tutorials but they all atone to some specific thing that I can't draw any useful information out of that would help me.

Comment: perhaps don't use Emission for the red part (and the white part either) and instead Diffuse or a mix of Emission and Diffuse, and use a light to make the color bounce towards the wall?

Comment: @moonboots i guess i'll try that but know that i have no clue how i even go about doing it, if you weren't able to guess i have no clue what i'm doing or where to even start, so asking me a question doesn't help. I just want a way to make this work since i can't use photoshop for this anymore and i thought i'd have more freedom in Blender, but nothing in this software makes sense to me and there isn't one thing about it that's straight forward.

Comment: please show your current Node Shader or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Also, try taking some compositing tutorials. Or just take this file into photoshop and add effects. (since you now have the 3d image)

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf if i only wanted a 3d image i'd not have to use Blender, it can be done in Photoshop and i don't want basic ass effects but simulated ones. I'd obviously not be here if i wanted a simple 3d image would i?

Comment: @moonboots Here's a save file - https://pasteall.org/blend/4e7fe41bde7841d89572d1fffb53415c

I'm currently trying to use Diffuse and Emission and seeing what works, I've noticed that i get weird artifacts like color noise, would you know why that is?

Answer (score 7):

This image shows every sign of being a negative. (The light is acting as a shadow.)

You could use negative lights.. but that might be a bit confusing.

Here, some faces of the logo-object have been given a strong emission in the inverse color of your logo's red, and some faces in the crevices, pure white emission. All emission is wound up to about 30. The rest of the object is a dark grey, (Hex:494949), in a black World. That produces the image on the left, when rendered in Cycles, deliberately sampling low to generate some noise...

[image]

When inverted in the compositor, the render is as on the right, above.

I think changing the background to a grey, while maintaining this lighting effect  will take some more compositing tricks, masking it by background object ID?

Comment: I believe the pixelated edges come from such a high emissive value.  It's overpowering in the integration algorithm.  My initial suggestion was going to be to lower all the values and use the compositor to hit the final coloration you want, but you guys already have some great answers.

Comment: Specifically talking about the edge pixels where the blue noise pattern for sub-pixel sampling should produce its own 'anti-aliasing' effect instead of these jaggies.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Ahh.. good thoughts. Have I missed a conversation? If you have any clues, or want to experiment, I can share the .blend. Fix not obvious to me.

Comment: Theory may not be right, I can't get anything conclusive.

Comment: @Robin Betts Damn, i didn't think people would really try to help this much. And yea you're right when i created the effect i was using Photoshop 3D (when this was still possible) and a easy way to make an effect like this was to make the shadow colored instead of different lights. I will try to implement this technique although it's a little hard to understand the process since this is the first time i'm using blender. I will try and learn from your feedback tho, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it is both a question of material and light settings, here is a try:

[image]

Here is the node setup for the background, no metallic, set the *Roughness* so that it scatters the light as much as you want, no *Transmission* (it is made for glass):

[image]

I have used a Diffuse only for the red color, I count on the lights for the bouncing lights:

[image]

I've created several red spot lights around the scene (so it's a bit of cheating as I didn't count on the reflexion of the logo only), and put them close to the logo:

[image]

Comment: Woa thank you very much for the advice! i thought so about making the light do the work but i didn't know how to achieve that or where to even start. And yea i had no clue what transmission was for, sounded like it would do something. I will try to make it happen now with what you've mentioned. once again, thank you very much!